# Laravel belongsTo() returns null for first relation in result

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

i have 2 models

1. **Meals**

   - Migration:

     | id(UUID) | name | price |
     | --- | --- | --- |
     | 0f25bde7-f461-4fa3-8a2c-f2cf65d5e76c | Chicken | 950 |
     | 2e5f270b-9386-445a-afac-c8c130ad83be | Lamb | 1500 |
     | e02cd4b5-3572-400f-a8de-8dda8bb45e54 | Honey | 2200 |
   - Relations:

     ```
     public function ordered_meals()
     {
       return $this->hasMany(OrderedMeal::class, 'meal_id');
     }
     ```
2. **Ordered Meals**

   - Migration:

     | id(INT) | meal_id | quantity |
     | --- | --- | --- |
     | 54 | 0f25bde7-f461-4fa3-8a2c-f2cf65d5e76c | 9 |
     | 55 | 2e5f270b-9386-445a-afac-c8c130ad83be | 1 |
     | 56 | 0f25bde7-f461-4fa3-8a2c-f2cf65d5e76c | 2 |
   - Relations:

     ```
     public function meal()
     {
       return $this->belongsTo(Meal::class, 'meal_id');
     }
     ```

when i call the the `OrderedMeal::with(['meal'])->get()` the first ordered meal have a relationship null, even when the `meal_id` is **present**,**exists** in the `meals table`

**Result:**

```
[
 {
  "id": 54,
  "cost": "8550"
  "meal_id": "0f25bde7-f461-4fa3-8a2c-f2cf65d5e76c",
  "name": "1",
  "meal": null,
 "quantity": "9"
 },
 {
  "id": 55,
  "cost": "1500"
  "meal_id": "2e5f270b-9386-445a-afac-c8c130ad83be",
  "meal": {
          "id": "2e5f270b-9386-445a-afac-c8c130ad83be",
          "name": "Lamb",
          "price": "1500.00"
         }
 "quantity": "1"
 },
{
 "id": 56,
 "cost": "4400"
 "meal_id": "e02cd4b5-3572-400f-a8de-8dda8bb45e54",
 "meal": {
          "id": "e02cd4b5-3572-400f-a8de-8dda8bb45e54",
          "name": "Chicken",
          "price": "2200",
        }
  "quantity": "2"
 }
]
```

What could be the problem as am certain the relationship are properly defined, and data is present in database

Comment: Have you noticed if the value stored in your database has any extra space?

Comment: I checked when I run a direct MySQL command the result returns fine

Comment: try like this `OrderedMeal::with('meal')->get()`

Comment: @Haron tried that also didn't work, just confused as to why the rest is showing up but the first isn't